# Browser not letting me make a request through Angular/Javascript soap client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soap, websocket, ionic-framework

I've tried **everything**, and the only way I seemed to get a concrete "POST" to the SOAP server was using NODE.js.
Is there actually a way to make a post to a soap server through the browser? I'm making an Ionic app and need to make calls for queries through this websocket..
Any help would be extremly helpful.
Thanks.

p.s.: The configuration is correct because it worked using POSTMAN & node too the same way I'm doing with Javascript. (400 (Bad Request) is always happening)

Comment: Do you have any error with origins?

Comment: sounds like possibly CORS related.  Browser same origin policy is different than Postman or node

Comment: It is definitly CORS related. The thing is, how would I get this to work with no backend doing this for me, meaning only Ionic/angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant make cross-origin . This is for security reasons.
What you can do is to  add http header to the response from the server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

In this site you can find more information 
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is what I had in mind but I have an extension on chrome that does this, so I don't know if itt'l work. I'll try though, Thanks!